# Problems with creating a file in android

Tags: android, file, text, createfile

i would like to do a simple operation. Create a file in android, but i don't know why. android didn't create this file. Android stop between debug 2 and debug 3.The folder is not created. I don't understand why.

```
try {
File inventoryDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ludovic");
String userfile = "/session.txt";
if (!inventoryDir.exists()){
inventoryDir.mkdirs();
Log.i("debug","debug 1");   
}
File userFile = new File(inventoryDir, userfile);
Log.i("debug","file path "+userFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    Log.i("debug","debug 2");           
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(userFile);
                    Log.i("debug","debug 3");
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    Log.i("debug","debug 4");
                    bw.write("teste d'ecriture");
                    Log.i("debug","debug 5");
                    bw.close();
                    Log.i("debug","debug 6");
                    Log.i("debug","enregistre");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i("debug","non enregistre");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

i have test this code

```
    try { // catches IOException below
                    final String TESTSTRING = new String("Hello Android");

                    // ##### Write a file to the disk #####
                    /* We have to use the openFileOutput()-method
                     * the ActivityContext provides, to
                     * protect your file from others and
                     * This is done for security-reasons.
                     * We chose MODE_WORLD_READABLE, because
                     *  we have nothing to hide in our file */             
                    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("samplefile.txt",
                                                            MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 

                    // Write the string to the file
                    osw.write(TESTSTRING);
                    /* ensure that everything is
                     * really written out and close */
                    osw.flush();
                    osw.close();
```

Whith this code, i didn't have problem's to create file but i don't find this file if i search with windows explorer.

Comment: i use this permission
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>

Comment: Can you post the Logcat content that we can know exactly what Exception was thrown.

Comment: it's a warning: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/ludovic/session.txt (Permission denied).

Comment: lol, it clearly says the problem there. post your manifest, you must have set your permissions wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="byd.eagle"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>  
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".EagleBackup"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Look at this code sample. The location where the uses-permission declared is the key. Just try both in and out the activity!

Comment: tank's. I never have supposed it was for this permission.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
inventoryDir.mkdirs();
```

to

```
inventoryDir.mkdir();
```

Latest:

```
 File inventoryDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ludovic");
      if (!(inventoryDir.exists())){
      inventoryDir.mkdir();
      }
```

and also WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in Manifest file

EDITED:

```
File inventoryDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ludovic/");
String userfile = "session.txt";
if (!(inventoryDir.exists())){
inventoryDir.mkdir();
Log.i("debug","debug 1");   
}
File userFile = new File(inventoryDir, userfile); 
 try {          
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(mFile);       
} catch (IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
out.print("some text");
out.close();
}
```

Comment: similar result. they have just this before
public class Main extends Activity{
 FileOutputStream fos;
 
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
File inventoryDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ludovic/");
String userfile = "session.txt";
```

Comment: how about the folder, is the folder `ludovic` created?

Comment: If you did the change I asked the folder should be created. So I think there is some other problem somewhere else. Can you post your manifest file